# multicols, lstlisting and float

Tags: floats, listings, multicol

Using the following structure, how can I get the listing to stay on the same page, be it at the top or the bottom?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \lipsum[1]

        \begin{lstlisting}[float=*htp, frame=tb]
very
long
listing
spanning
several
lines
        \end{lstlisting}
        \lipsum[2-7]
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Floats in `multicols` are only "full line" and always go on the following page. Put the `lstlisting` environment earlier in the input.

Comment: @egreg: Please turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Floats in `multicols` are only "full line" and always go on the following page.

Put the `lstlisting` environment earlier in the input, so that it can float to the desired page.